# Where to put my $(document).ready(function(){ When I have methods in a .js

Tags: jquery

I created a somefile.js where somefile.js contains some jQuery method.  So for instance it contains this function:

```
function showWindow(divID)
{
    var dialogDiv = $(divID);

    dialogDiv.dialog
    (
        {
            bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'blind'
        }
    )

    dialogDiv.dialog("open");
}
```

So in my .aspx page (or whatever, it could be an .html), I have a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="showPopUp('testDiv')" value="Click Me!" />
```

My question is, we're going to use showPopUp all over in our app.  If it's called from an onClick event, then where do I put my  $(document).ready(function() since this code is not in the page, but in a .js file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put it in the Javascript file if you want.  If you're attaching listeners with the onclick attribute like that, you don't actually need to use $(document).ready().

However, it's generally considered better form to not use the onclick attribute, and attach the listener in Javascript, like so:

`<input type = "button" class = "showPopup" id = "testDiv" value = "Click Me!" />`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.showPopup").click(function(){
    showWindow($(this).id);
  }

  function showWindow(id){...}
}
```

You can put that javascript in the head of the document like ~ricebowl said.

Comment: I applaud your suggestion of using classes to identify the input, rather than my own -naive and stupid- method. Good call! =)

Answer (score 5):

Put the `$(document).ready(...);` in the `head` of the (x)html page (or, indeed, .php, .aspx, etc) as normal, just so long as you make sure that it comes after the linked `script` file (to load your somefile.js) and, of course, the link to your jQuery:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(
     function() {
        $('input[type=button]').click().showPopUp('testDiv');
     }
    )
</script>

</head>
```

---

**Edited** to note that I feel that I'm missing something obvious in your question. Please comment if I'm being completely obvious and missing your point...

Answer (score 0):

The "right" technical answer will vary by framework (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.)  If you want to use this function throughout your application, you can use a script tag:

```
<script type="javascript" src="somefile.js" />
```

That tag can be included in a "page header include", implemented in whatever way is best.  For example, in ASP.NET I'd include that tag in the Master page.

Answer (score 0):

You got to do this: Split the function into two:

MakeDialog(divID) //this way you prepare the div to be a dialog and ShowDialog(divID) //this is where you show the dialog

```
//document load
$(document).ready(function(){
     MakeDialog(divId);//prepa
});

function makeDialog(divID)
{
    var dialogDiv = $(divID);

    dialogDiv.dialog
    (
        {
            bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            show: 'blind'
        }
    )   
}

function showWindow(divId)
{
 dialogDiv.dialog("open");
}
```

HTH