# The document ready function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I understand well it is better to put scripts at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag: `</body>`

But with jQuery it is common to use the $(document).ready(function() to wrap the jQuery methods. I suppose this makes the JQuery run only after the page is loaded? if so:

- If I put the jQuery in the head, I have to use the `$(document).ready(function(){}` or the shorter `$(function(){}`

code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // jQuery methods go here...
}
```

- If I put the jQuery just before the closing body tag, I do not need the $(document).ready(function(){}
- The two option are equivalent and both correct

Is that right?

Comment: Not quite equivalent but they are both correct...

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631007/where-to-put-my-document-readyfunction-when-i-have-methods-in-a-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct but:
1. If file is large (lots of code) `$(document).ready(function()` start work when document is loaded 100%.
2. If file is large (lots of code) after `</body>` you can get errors becouse users can start to do something when documents loading still in progress.
 If file (code content) small you can't see any diference

Comment: I suppose you mean BEFORE </body>